# How can I max black mage efficiently

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics

The black mage job requires alot of JPs.

I tried maxing it but sending only Ramza, I thought i would kill all enemies but one and send him retreating with low HPs so i could use focus.

However I am already level 50 so usually in a random encounter Ramza will have to face 5 enemies with 300HPs.

Is there a way or specific battle which could be used for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JP is earned from the job** you have equipped **not the skills** you are using.

The following should work in pretty much any random encounter (with or without other party members),

- Set Ramza's job to Wizard.
- Set Ramza's secondary skill set to Guts (special Squire skills) and have Yell/Tailwind learned (the Guts skill that gives +1 speed, I could be wrong on the names).
- Enter a battle and continuously cast Yell/Tailwind. Repeat this until you have the desired amount of JP.

This is just one of many ways to farm JP effectively. Other ways can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/188983/73957).

Comment: Imo the most efficient way to farm jp is to just beat on your own characters (leave one enemy in the map to ignore), while using chakra to recover health and mana.  Can be done on any map, though maps with trash are obviously best.